# storing datagrid selected value into array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, datagridview

I am implementing a simple shopping cart, I have a SQL Stored procedure that returns all the products and stores them into a DataGridView, the seller selects one product and types the required quantity, for e.g. 2.

The seller can select products multiple times so I need to store the Code and the Quantity of the selected product every time the seller clicks the button "Add to cart" so that in the end I can use that data to process the sale and show the total. (I’m thinking of an array but If you could suggest me a better solution I would be thankful, I hope you can help me).

Here's what I have so far:
[Sales Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdOV4.png)

The "cod" is the product's code that I retrieve from the selected product.

This is the code from the Process Sale Button:

```
private void btnCarrito_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
ProcessSale s = new ProcessSale();

        if (cod != "")
        {
            if (txtQuantity.Text != "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show(s.AddToCart(Convert.ToInt32(cod), 
            Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantity.Text)), "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
            MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You need to sell at least 1 unit", "", 
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You need to select a product", "", 
           MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }}
```

This is the code at ProcessSale:

```
public string AddToCart(int cod, int quantity)
    {
        string message= "";

        //Cleary this n=0 is wrong and the for is not going to work
        //I don't know what to set n because the Array is going to increase
        //every time the seller adds a product to the cart
        int n = 0;
        int[][] array = new int[2][];
        for (int i = 1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            array[n][n] = cod;
            array[n][n+1] = quantity;
            n++;
        }

       // I believe it should return the Array
        return array;
    }
```

What I would like it to return would be something like this:

```
[1][20] //Which means the product with code 1 was selected with 20 units, for 
    //e.g. Aspirin 20 units

[1][20]



[2][2]
```

and so on...

My problem is the for loop needs a variable that sets its end, in this case n, but n would be the lenght of the terms that will populate the array, but in this case everytime I click on add to cart the array will be 1 position bigger, I hope I explained myself.

Comment: you're question contents are fine, except you never asked any question.  what exactly is the issue you are having trouble figuring out?

Comment: I'm sorry Robert. My problem is  the for loop needs a variable that sets its end, in this case n, but n would be the lenght of the terms that will populate the array, but in  this case everytime I click on add to cart the array will be 1 position bigger, I hope I explained myself.

Comment: You could use a better data structure than a multidimensional array (this isn't the 80's), which makes things clearer and easier to work with. Create a `SalesOrder` class for example with two properties: `Cod` and `Quantity`, then create a collection (such as a `List<SalesOrder>`) of those sales orders when someone clicks the `ProcessSale` button. Process each line of your `DataGrid`, and decide whether you need to add a new `SalesOrder` to your `List` or just increase the quantity of an existing one (because that row has the same `Cod` as an item in your `List<SalesOrder`

Comment: @Aceman You're just fine, but if you would be so kind please edit your answer to clarify that.

Comment: Thank you Mashton and Robert, I will try to do it now.